# Powershell - script to sort photos by dimensions, having issues evaluating 'numbers'

Tags: string, image, powershell, integer, dimensions

I'm trying to write a Powershell script to sort out thousands of photos into respective folders based on their image width.

I would like:

- photos under 300px wide to be classed as small.
- photos between 301px and 799px to be classed as medium.
- photos 800px and over to be classed as large.

I found this great function which I'm using:
[MS technet article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/02/06/use-powershell-to-find-metadata-from-photograph-files.aspx)

The problem is that Powershell seems to be having issues evaluating numbers/images over 1000px wide correctly.

The code I have is here (admittedly not very pretty/streamlined):

```
Function Get-FileMetaData
{
Param([string[]]$folder)
foreach($sFolder in $folder)
{
$a = 0
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$objFolder = $objShell.namespace($sFolder)

foreach ($File in $objFolder.items())
{ 
 $FileMetaData = New-Object PSOBJECT
  for ($a ; $a  -le 266; $a++)
   { 
     if($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a))
       {
         $hash += @{$($objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $a))  =
               $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a)) }
        $FileMetaData | Add-Member $hash
        $hash.clear() 
       } #end if
   } #end for 
 $a=0
 $FileMetaData
} #end foreach $file
} #end foreach $sfolder
} #end Get-FileMetaData

$photodir="C:\photos\"
Get-FileMetaData -folder $photodir | select path,dimensions | 
ForEach-Object -Process {

if ($_.dimensions -ne $null){
$filename=$_.path;
$dimensions=$($_.dimensions);
$dimensions_split=$dimensions.split();
$dimensions_width=$($dimensions_split[0]);

if ($dimensions_width -gt "799"){"$filename is $dimensions_width so is large";"---";}
if (($dimensions_width -lt "800") -and ($dimensions_width -gt "300")){"$filename is     $dimensions_width so is medium";"---";}
if ($dimensions_width -lt "300"){"$filename is $dimensions_width so is small";"---";}
```

This gives the results:

```
C:\photos\logo1024x1024.jpg is ‪1024 so is small
---
C:\photos\logo128x128.jpg is ‪128 so is small
---
C:\photos\logo1600x1600.jpg is ‪1600 so is small
---
C:\photos\logo1920x1080.jpg is ‪1920 so is small
---
C:\photos\logo512x512.jpg is ‪512 so is medium
---
C:\photos\logo960x960.jpg is ‪960 so is large
---
```

So I thought maybe it's an issue because they are strings. What if I force them to be integers hopefully Powershell can evaluate them correctly:

```
if ([int]$dimensions_width -gt 800){"$filename is $dimensions_width so is large";"---";}
```

This gives an error:

```
Cannot convert value "‪1024" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was 
not in a correct format."
At C:\scripts\sort_photos_sm_md_lg.ps1:39 
char:9
+     if ([int]$dimensions_width -gt 799){"$filename is $dimensions_width so 
is la ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
```

Which makes no sense to me as 1024 looks like an integer to me?

If I do it this way instead, Powershell likes the syntax but still cannot evaluate it correctly:

```
if (($dimensions_width -as [int]) -gt 799){"$filename is $dimensions_width so is large";"---";}
```

Despite going through several pages of Google results I cannot find an answer.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for a work-around, [GDI+ can be used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xddt0dz7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to read a large variety of file metadata. Just opening the file as [`Drawing.Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) provides dimensions too. Like so,

```
# Load the drawing assembly
add-type -assemblyname System.Drawing
# Open the image
$img = new-object Drawing.Bitmap("C:\MyBigImage.jpg")
# Print dimensions
$("w:{0} h:{1}" -f $img.Width, $img.Height)
w:3264 h:2448 # Quite big a picture
# Don't forget to dispose the bitmap
$img.Dispose()
```

Comment: Great - many thanks, that worked fine `gci -Filter *.jpg c:\photos | % {
$filename = $_.FullName
# Load the drawing assembly
add-type -assemblyname System.Drawing
# Open the image
$img = new-object Drawing.Bitmap("$filename")
# Print dimensions
$("w:{0} h:{1}" -f $img.Width, $img.Height)
if ($img.width  -gt 799){"$filename is $img.width so is large";"---";}
#w:3264 h:2448 # Quite big a picture
# Don't forget to dispose the bitmap
$img.Dispose()
}`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$photodir= "C:\photos"
Get-FileMetaData -folder $photodir | select percorso,dimensioni | 
ForEach-Object -Process {
    if ($_.dimensioni -ne $null)
    {
        $filename=$_.percorso;
        $dimensions=$($_.dimensioni);
        $dimensions_width= [int](-join ((( $dimensions -split ' ' )[0]).ToCharArray() )[1..4])
    }

    switch  ($dimensions_width) 
    {
        {$_ -gt 799} {"$filename is $dimensions_width so is large";"---";break}
        {$_ -lt 800 -and $dimensions_width -gt 300} {"$filename is     $dimensions_width so is medium";"---";break}
        default {"$filename is $dimensions_width so is small"; "---";break}
    }
}
```

The problem as mentioned by @Raf is an illegal character after the split, but is not a white space but a `[char][int]8234` value that is not affected by the `trim()` method.

Comment: Many thanks CB, this does indeed work! However, when I compare it to the workaround above using GDI+ posted by vonPryz it shows that the GetFileMetaData function is dramatically slower at parsing the images. The GDI+ method is probably about 80% faster! Many thanks for fixing/completing my original code for me though. Unfortunately I don't have enough rep power to award any points for this...

Comment: @TristanP never mind... I answer to help and not for votes ;). Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely leading or trailing an illegal character inside `$dimensions_width`. You can verify it by echoing `$dimensions_width.Length` which is the number of characters in a string:

```
...
$dimensions_width=$($dimensions_split[0]);
Write-Host ("Width " + $dimensions_width + ",Length " + $dimensions_width.Length)

if ($dimensions_width -gt "799")....
....
```

If on 1024 you get *Length* greater than 4 then this will be it. Try

```
$dimensions_width=$($dimensions_split[0].Trim() -replace "`n|`r|`t","");
```

to get rid of white spaces.

Comment: Thanks Raf - you are correct, the length showed there was a hidden extra character. Unfortunately the trim did not fix it.